# app engine endpoints - some apis wont update after deploy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-endpoints

i believe this problem started after google released the new app engine sdk version 1.8.6, because since then i've been having problems.

i've been developing an app-engine connected android application, i started using app engine about a month ago and everything seemed to be working good, until last wednesday, then my server started responding with error 503 on every request i tried to make, i was really frustrated and didn't know what to do, i tried everything - reloading a previous working version, reinstall eclipse, reinstall the SDKs and so on..

now after a lot of tests i can say this:
when i tried to create a new project and copy in the backup files, not of the endpoints showed up in the API explorer, but when i tried to create a new entity and generate and endpoint class for it then it did update (took a few minutes to update)

so my conclusion is that my code that i created in the previous environment doesn't work now and i have no idea why, in the IDE there seems to be no problems and the deployment is successful.

if you have any ideas why this is happening i would love to know, i'm breaking my head and just a step away from committing suicide :P

this is the code for the Entity that doesn't work:

```
package com.fancypants.events;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.GeoPt;

@Entity
public class Event{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private Boolean active = true;

// created at
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "careated_at")
private Date createdAt;

// updated at
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "updated_at")
private Date updatedAt;

//location
private GeoPt location;

//info
private String title;
private String description;
private Long creatorId;


//users
private List<Long> users = new ArrayList<User>();

@Transient
private int distance; //in meters, calculated in client after fetching

//comments
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "vibe")
private List<Comment> comments;

//pictures
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "vibe")
private List<Picture> pictures;

public Event(){

}

@PrePersist
void createdAt() {
    if (this.createdAt == null){
        this.createdAt = this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }
}

@PreUpdate
void updatedAt() {
    this.updatedAt = new Date();
}

//getters and setters
}
```

so im really confused, this might be a problem with the project settings, because honestly i don't really know whats happening there :P
although there are no errors and the deployment is successful + this code was working perfectly good 6 days ago...

so please help! if you need a screenshot of anything please tell me! cheers!

Comment: how do you learned to add the updatedAt and createdAt fields that way? I'm trying this from a week but it doesn't work. Can you post just a link on tutorials or the documentation? I'm talking specifically about google cloud endpoints

Comment: what are you trying to make? try to look [here](http://www.developerscrappad.com/228/java/java-ee/ejb3-jpa-dealing-with-date-time-and-timestamp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently there have been some issues with GAE, after finding this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10146) i realized the problem was with the new version of the app engine SDK, they rolled back the version and it seems to be working fine now